# Does "service mysql start" start the mysql server or client?

Tags: mysql, redhat

Does "service mysql start" start the mysql server or client?

I have done as much searching on this topic as I can, and the answers do seem all over the place. Some sites state that the "service mysql start" starts the server, while others state that one must use "service mysqld start": e.g.: http://theos.in/desktop-linux/tip-that-matters/how-do-i-restart-mysql-server/

To elaborate some more - my understanding is that "mysql" is the process that represents the client interface that connects to a mysql server (either remote or local) and "mysqld" is the process for the server. I would assume that "service mysql start" would only start the mysql client (not the server) and I can use this client to connect to any mysql server. And if I haven't used "service mysqld start", no server would have been started on the local host and therefore I can't use the mysql client to connect to any local mysql server. Is my understanding correct?

Also, I am using a Red Hat server.

Any clarifications and explanations most appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Your question is rather off-topic here, because it's not about programming. [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) would be the right place here at StackExchange for this kind of question. But a note from me: It's starting the server, see [RedHats documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-MySQL.html)

Comment: It starts the server. The client is the interface between the user and the server, or the programming language and the server.

Comment: @VMai - The link that you provided states that to start the server, the following command is needed: "service mysqld start"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql client is never (AFAIK) run as a service, so

```
service mysql start
```

will start mysql server. To be precise, this will start service that is described in /etc/init.d/mysql script.

Some distributions name their init script differently, for example mysqld. So you should just check your /etc/init.d/

You can check what exactly that scipt is doing, even if you don't know bash. 
First few lines should contain short description, in case of my ubuntu installation it is:

```
# cat /etc/init.d/mysql
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MySQL database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
```

So as you can see, mysql service script takes care of mysqld daemon (process). As opposed to mysql binary, found for example in /usr/bin which is client program and doesn't require any service to be running on your OS.

To sum everything up:

```
# service mysql start
```

will start server (daemon/service), then you can connect to it with

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This is an excellent summary and clarification - "To sum everything up:

# service mysql start
will start server (daemon/service), then you can connect to it with

$ mysql -u root -p" - This sums everything perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command "service mysqld start" this will start the mysql server in RHEL.
Actally the name "mysqld" depends on init.d scripts name. If it's mentioned as "mysql" in init.d scripts "mysql" will work. This variates from distro to distro.

Answer (score 0):

in my case
systemctl restart rh-mysql57-mysqld.service